# How to write html with javascript and display it on a slider?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a basic slider that runs through images every 5 seconds while using javascript. My slider works just fine, but I'm not wanting to use it as an image slider anymore. I'm wanting to create a div with some more html design features and post that within my slider instead of my images. Going by this code below, what would I have to change and add to make it work?

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Ad Slider</title>
 <style>
 #slider
 {
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
 }
 #sliderImages
 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #06c;
border-radius: 10px;
 }
 </style>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "sky.jpg";
var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "chatImage.jpg";
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "orange.jpg";
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id = "slider">
    <img id = "sliderImages" src = "sky.jpg" name = "slide" />
    <script type = "text/javascript">
   var sliderAd = 1
   function slideAds()
   {
      if (!document.images)
      {
     return;
      }
      document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+sliderAd+".src")
      if (sliderAd < 3)
      {
         sliderAd++;
      }
      else
      {
     sliderAd = 1;
      }
      setTimeout("slideAds()",5000)
   }
   slideAds()
</script>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now instead of adding those images, how can I add this type of content but working the same way like the images were?

```
 <div>
    <p>Some Content</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: finding content slider plugins and code is not hard to do in a web search

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to write what you're looking for. Here's an augmented version of your code... You can toss whatever HTML you want into the innerHTML.

In the future, you're better of using Google to read up on the basics of Javascript...

```
<div id = "container">
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
MAXSLIDES = 2
slideText = 1

function slideAds() {
    container = document.getElementById("container")

    if(slideText == 1) {
        container.innerHTML = "test1"
    } else if (slideText == 2) {
        container.innerHTML = "test2"
    }

    slideText += 1
    if(slideText > MAXSLIDES) { slideText = 1 }
    setTimeout("slideAds()",5000);
}

slideAds()

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. I tried a few ways but kept failing lol I'm more familiar with php but learning javascript. Still in college lol :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is just to create an array of html you need, and than iterate through it inserting in each string as html in your holder div: here is an example from your question the only thing I used jQuery it is much easier that way.

```
 <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Ad Slider</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #slider
   {
      width: 800px;
      height: 200px;
   }
   #sliderImages
   {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #06c;
  border-radius: 10px;
   }
   </style>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var arrayOfDiv = new Array();
arrayOfDiv[0] = "<div style='background-color:#FF0'>this is first div!</div>";
arrayOfDiv[1] = "<div style='background-color:#0ff'>this is second div!</div>";
arrayOfDiv[2] = "<div style='background-color:#f0f'>this is third div!</div>";

      var sliderAd = 0;
     function slideAds()
     {

        $("#sliderImages").html(arrayOfDiv[sliderAd]);
        if (sliderAd < arrayOfDiv.length-1)
        {
           sliderAd++;
        }
        else
        {
       sliderAd = 0;
        }
        setTimeout("slideAds()",5000);
     }

      $(function(){
       slideAds();  
     });
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id = "slider">
      <div id = "sliderImages" ></div>

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: thanks works great, only complaint is, while typing in the div, I can't align the code the way I like lol I have to keep every p tag, div,etc... all in one line which makes it a little annoying but overall works great so I'm happy lol have a great day

Comment: wrap your text with another div and give that div margin or parent div padding. And read some articles about that because it is a basics of layout in html.     `var arrayOfDiv = new Array(); arrayOfDiv[0] = "<div style='background-color:#FF0'><div style='width:200px;margin:auto' >this is first div!</div></div>";
    arrayOfDiv[1] = "<div style='background-color:#0ff;padding:100px;'><div style='width:200px;' >this is second div!</div>";
    arrayOfDiv[2] = "<div style='background-color:#f0f'>this is third div!</div>";`